# CSS Style not working after refreshing the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to refresh a div using jQuery, but after refreshing my CSS doesn't work.

FYI : I dynamically set CSS,

```
document.getElementById("sai").style.color = "green";



window.setInterval('refresh()', 1000);  
      function refresh() {
        $('#nav-tabContent').load(' #nav-tabContent')

      }
```

After refreshing the div, green is not used.

Comment: What is this `$('#nav-tabContent').load(' #nav-tabContent')`supposed to do? That's not how [`$.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is supposed to work. Where is teh element with `id="sai"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add color like this:

```
document.getElementById("sai").style.color = "green";
```

you add it as an inline style.

When you rerender the div again, the inline styles that you add dynamically disappears. You should add the `color` again after this action like below:

```
window.setInterval('refresh()', 1000);  
      function refresh() {
        $('#nav-tabContent').load(' #nav-tabContent');
        document.getElementById("sai").style.color = "green";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the CSS style again after the refresh as it is dynamically applied. When you refresh the div, the browser will render it again with the code it contains statically and that is why the dynamically added css will not be applied.

Comment: how can i apply css again?

Comment: <script>
document.getElementById("srini").style.color = "green";
window.setInterval('refresh()', 1000);  
      function refresh() {
        $('#nav-tabContent').load(' #nav-tabContent')
  document.getElementById("srini").style.color = "green";
      }
</script>

Comment: After you call the load() method you should call document.getElementById("sai").style.color = "green"; line again. The final function shoild look like: window.setInterval('refresh()', 1000);  
      function refresh() {
        $('#nav-tabContent').load(' #nav-tabContent');
document.getElementById("srini").style.color = "green"; 
      }

Answer (score 0):

It should be written this way. The link for the working code is [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/m41dgroj/3/)

```
window.setInterval('refresh()', 1000);  
      function refresh() {
        $('#nav-tabContent').load(' #nav-tabContent')
      }
document.getElementById("sai").style.color = "green";
```